# Crear vista MySQL con JOIN con condición variable

Tags: mysql, join, vistas

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.name,
    t1.code,
    t2.country,
    t2.user_id,
    IF(
        t2.fee_fixed IS NOT NULL,
        t2.fee_fixed,
        t1.fee_fixed
    ) fee_fixed,
    IF(
        t2.fee_fixed_currency IS NOT NULL,
        t2.fee_fixed_currency,
        t1.fee_fixed_currency
    ) fee_fixed_currency,
    IF(
        t2.fee_percent IS NOT NULL,
        t2.fee_percent,
        t1.fee_percent
    ) fee_percent,
    t2.status,
    t2.method_key 
FROM 
    table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id
    AND t2.user_id = 131 
WHERE 
    t1.status = 1
```

Mi pregunta es, siendo el valor de user_id un valor variable, ¿cómo puedo transformar esta query en una vista?
Al crear la vista con el JOIN y solo la primera condición, posteriormente al realizar una query pasando como condición user_id = 131, no retorna todos los registros de la tabla1, es decir, se pierde el LEFT JOIN

Muchas gracias

Comment: Esa condicion que pones en el left join bien podría ir en el WHERE porque no es un criterio de asociación entre las dos tablas. Así pues, podrías tener la proyección, el join, sin ese user_id = 111 y más bien, cuando hagas select * from vista_tablas WHERE vista_tablas.user_id = 111

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, no obtengo el mismo resultado si muevo la condición del user_id al where. En la consulta, estoy realizando un LEFT JOIN para que, siempre, independiente de los registros de la tabla 2, me retorne todos los registros de la tabla1. En este caso, como user_id pertence a la tabla2, si muevo la condición al WHERE, solo me retornará los registros que coincidan en la tabla2

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cuál es la idea de mostrar todos los registros de table1 si el filtro está en table2... Es lógico que al filtrar por table2, te reducirá lo que obtienes de table1 ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de los registros de cada tabla, y lo que esperas conseguir con este SELECT? Gracias.